# How to add two listviews in a fragment in android layout?

Tags: android, xml, listview

i'm trying display two listviews in a fragment. but i'm getting problems in xml file itself. I am using sherlock fragment.
Also one list should be displayed on 2/3 space of the screen and another list on 1/3 of the screen space. please can u help? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DEF7C6"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#CFCACC" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/addbutton"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonadd" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Am I crazy or is there only 1 list view up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for the ListViews only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DEF7C6"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:entries="@array/l1"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" >
</ListView>


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:entries="@array/l2"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note the "weight" parameter to achieve the 2/3 - 1/3 proportion. You should look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) if you want to add list view elements dynamically.

If you want other elements instead of the second `ListView` just change it for a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`.